# ATX12V to EPS12V Adapter with DP55WG?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, adapter

I bought a new Intel DP55WG Motherboard to upgrade an old computer.
My old Motherboard and Power Supply used a 2x2 pin connector (ATX12V) and my new motherboard uses a 4x2 pin connector (EPS12V).

My question is - can I use an adapter to connect my 2x2 pin connector, coming out of my power suuply, to the 4x2 pin connector in my motherboard? Can it cause problems? Do I need I new power supply?

Answer (score 0):

I have built quite a few machines lately with second generation Core processors and they have all come with 4x2 power inputs, however, they all state that it is optional and perfectly safe to use just a 2x2.

Edit --

That being said, after reading the manual for your board, it looks like you are required to use a 2x4 connector AND have a SATA power connector to the motherboard.

Comment: can this power supply be used? I'm not sure if the 2x (2x2) connectors can act as a 4x2. http://www.in-win.com.tw/products_power_series.php?cat_id=3&series_id=70